# Define filter for DecorateAllWith() method in structure-map 3

Tags: c#, decorator, ioc-container, structuremap

I used following statement to decorate all my `ICommandHandlers<>` with `Decorator1<>`:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
   x.For(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)).DecorateAllWith(typeof(Decorator1<>));
});
```

But because `Decorator1<>` implements `ICommandHandlers<>`, the `Decorator1<>` class decorates itself too.

So, the problem is that the `Decorator1` registers inadvertently, when I register all the `ICommandHandler<>`'s.
How can I filter `DecorateWithAll()`to decorate all `ICommandHandler<>`, except `Decorator1<>`?

Comment: Is the problem that you are inadvertently registering `Decorator1` when you register all the `ICommandHandler<>`'s?

Comment: @qujck: Yeah, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ObjectFactory`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structuremap-users/S7nBib95zh0) is obsolete.

You can exclude `Decorator1<>` from being registered as a vanilla `ICommandHandler<>` with code like this:

```
var container = new Container(config =>
{
    config.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        scanner.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
        scanner.Exclude(t => t == typeof(Decorator1<>));
        scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
    });
    config.For(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)).DecorateAllWith(typeof(Decorator1<>));
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

For multiple modules you can use [The Registry DSL](http://docs.structuremap.net/RegistryDSL.htm) to compose a portion of your application

```
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;

public class CommandHandlerRegistry : Registry
{
    public CommandHandlerRegistry()
    {
        Scan(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
            scanner.Exclude(t => t == typeof(Decorator1<>));
            scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
        });
        For(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)).DecorateAllWith(typeof(Decorator1<>));
    }
}
```

Only the Composition Root needs to be aware of all the `Registry` implementations.

```
 var container = new Container(config =>
{
    config.AddRegistry<CommandHandlerRegistry>();
});
```

You even have the option of finding all `Registry` instances at runtime (you still need to ensure all the required assemblies are loaded)

```
var container = new Container(config =>
{
    var registries = (
        from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        from type in assembly.DefinedTypes
        where typeof(Registry).IsAssignableFrom(type)
        where !type.IsAbstract
        where !type.Namespace.StartsWith("StructureMap")
        select Activator.CreateInstance(type))
        .Cast<Registry>();

    foreach (var registry in registries)
    {
        config.AddRegistry(registry);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have multiple modules in my application that each module has itself configuration file for IoC container, so I used `ObjectFactory.Configure`, to append each configuration to others, Is it possible to do this with `var container = new Container(...` too?